# How to load an image byte array into QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, gdi+, qgraphicsview

I'm building a module for an application and, this module should take a print from the screen and show it into a `QGraphicsView`.

This is my Print Screen code that saves the taken photo into a `jpg` file:

```
#include <gdiplus.h>

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid) {
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    UINT  num = 0;
    UINT  size = 0;

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if(size == 0)
        return -1; 

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if(pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
        return -1;

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);
    for(UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if( wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0 )
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;
        }    
    }
    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return 0;
}

void gdiscreen() {
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    IStream* istream;
    HRESULT res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &istream);
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    {
        HDC scrdc, memdc;
        HBITMAP membit;
        scrdc = ::GetDC(0);
        int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
        membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
        HBITMAP hOldBitmap =(HBITMAP) SelectObject(memdc, membit);
        BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        
        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(membit, NULL);
        CLSID clsid;
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid); //Type of image
        bitmap.Save(L"print.jpeg", &clsid, NULL); //Name of the file to save
        bitmap.Save(istream, &clsid, NULL);
        
        delete &clsid;
        DeleteObject(memdc);
        DeleteObject(membit);
        ::ReleaseDC(0,scrdc);
    }
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    istream->Release();
}

int main(){
    gdiscreen();
    return 0;
}
```

Where on this code could I get the necessary "image code" to run into a `QGraphicsView`?

Comment: You should do one thing at a time. Start to learn C++ properly, then you can open the Qt door :) By the way, never `delete` an automatic variable. You must only `delete` what was `new`ed.

Comment: I need it for my Graduation Work at School. I choose `C++` at the beginning of the year; so I got no choice than keep going. If you could help me I'd be very thankful

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I never said you shouldn't keep going. Actually I rather said the opposite, you should keep going, but the right way. C++ is not a language you can learn by try and guess. I'm not saying you should not use C++, I'm saying you should learn it properly to be able to use it. You could make use of [some good C++ books for that purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/11455384) (or a teacher, or online resources such as learncpp.com, etc...).

Comment: I got it and I'll keep studying. Is there any forum where I Could get the kind of answer that I'm looking for?

Comment: You can add a [`QGraphicsPixmapItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicspixmapitem.html) to add an image to your scene.

Comment: You seem to be using HBITMAP, and QImage has a static method: [QImage::fromHBITMAP(HBITMAP hbitmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#fromHBITMAP). What about `graphicsView.scene()->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage::fromHBITMAP(hbitmap));`?

Comment: `#include <gdiplus.h>`, do you have to use this for some reason? See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html

Comment: @kuybt6 Adding to what Fareanor said: Qt is an extremely powerful, extended and extensible toolkit. Its learning curve is not consistent: some basic aspects are quite easy to understand at first (leading you to the impression that "it's easy", even as a beginner) but, as you get to know it, you then realize its complexity (and the curve becomes reversed) along with its power. It may take months, if not years to **actually** master even its basic principles. I don't mean this to scare you away from it, but to carefully consider the implications. Be patient: learning is done by small steps.